# nomethoderror in contacts#new making contactform in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and i am currently stuck trying to create a contact form. 
I get the report saying : undefined method `name' for #, but in the i did create the method for name :
   create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
I'v tried to fix this error so i can preview the page, but i keep getting an error.  I hope one of you can help me, thanks in advance!

```html
NoMethodError in Contacts#new
Showing /home/nitrous/workspace/simplecodecast_saas/app/views/contacts/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `name' for #<Contact id: nil>
Extracted source (around line #7):

          
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>                  
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>       <---- (This is line 7)
      </div>
  
      <div class="form-group">

Rails.root: /home/nitrous/workspace/simplecodecast_saas

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_contacts_new_html_erb__2291340040590759835_34535240'
app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_contacts_new_html_erb__2291340040590759835_34535240'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

My routes.rb code:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'
```

and my contacts_controller.rb

```html
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
  
  def create
  end
end
```

I added this to my model: contact.rb

```html
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  
end
```

And the db file:

```html
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and last my html page

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="well">
  <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :comments %>
      <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  
      <% f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have `name` attribute in `Contact` model?

Comment: Did you create a `contacts` database table? If not run `rails g model contact name:string` and then `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Hmm. Did you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I ran the rake db_migrate after i made the changes in the table.

I created the create_contacts table with 
bundle exec rails generate migration create_contacts cmd

Its really strange,

Comment: I ran the bundle exec rails console cmd and it seems like my table is empty. :" Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
.bundle :001 > Contact.new
 => #<Contact id: nil> "
In the table file i made the create_table code and ran the rake db:migrate, which should create the table

Comment: Not necessarily. What's in `db/schema.rb`? UPD: well, you've found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix.
I ran the rake db:rollback cmd and then the rake db:migrate.
Now it is working.

Sorry for wasting your time :)  Hopefully someone else can benifit from this answer!

Comment: Thank you @Charli, it worked for me as well. You didn't waste my time :)